# Vimeo :domain-level embed privacy : How to handle video link if someone use inspect webpage and change video id

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I am planning to use Vimeo for hosting my educational video series which I want to restrict specific videos to specific user as per what plan / course they have purchased.

After lots of googling, I came across one option in Vimeo to set "domain-level embed privacy" so that only from my site video will be played.

But what if someone inspect webpage and change video url which is private?

---

Vimeo forum relevent link : https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:277888

### "If you want to keep your video's privacy set to domain-level embed privacy, one workaround is to embed the video on a domain you control, and then embed that page in your Android webapp."

is there any way to handle this as if someone tried many url changes then he can see video from my website even if I have set them private and domain level security.

In near future, I want to use same in my android app as well so that logged in user can see videos they allowed.

Thanks in advance.
Can someone guide me for this usecase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But what if someone inspects the webpage and changes the video url which is
>   private?

If someone inspects the webpage and changes the video url then the change will be local to their system and temporary. As they refresh page it will revert back to original. No website on earth can stop this from happening.

> is there any way to handle this as if someone tried many url changes
>   then he can see video from my website even if I have set them private
>   and domain level security.

Domain level security as far as I understand means that you can embed video on a website on a particular domain only such as - yourdomain.com. Changing the url of embedded video will not load any video as video is hosted on provided url only.

> In near future, I want to use same in my android app as well so that
>   logged in user can see videos they allowed.

In an android app you can load your page in a webview or inappbrowser. And on a website you can make certain pages accessible to authenticated user only. On top of that you can also implement record level security, so that a particular course is accessible only to people with subscription to that course.